# What is the best backend for React-Native hybrid app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, backend

I am currently developing a react native front end to be used as a mobile app as well as a web app. I am unsure which backend service to be using that will work with it. I am needing To use it for a ticket system. Anybody have recommendations and resources?

Comment: Firebase is very simple to use and works great with react. That's why I use it. It can do user authentication for you and the database is very simple to use. Also the first few GB database are free so it is great for testing. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I don't think so it is a question to StackOverflow. It's kinda opinion based